# Can the Dafny compiler be used with multiple dfy programs vs a single runtime?

Tags: compiler-construction, dafny

When compiling Dafny to, say, Javascript, in a trivial example like ComputeFib, it generates a 30kb file of which the last 40 lines are the actual code. This is obviously because it ships the runtime with it. Is there a way to have a lot of Dafny code exported and work with a single runtime instead of every compiled program bringing it's own runtime?